# Showing parameter/arguments with Delphi Jedi JCLDebug

Tags: delphi, jedi

When an error occurs in my Delphi XE5 application, in my exception handler I am trying to get Jedi Code Library's JCLDebug.pas to show any parameters of method calls listed on the stack. I was hoping to get this information in a similar way to the way the Delphi IDE shows this information in its Call Stack debug window when you break during an exception, like this:

> TestForm.DoSomething('A Test Parameter')
>
> TestForm.TTestForm.DoSomethingClick($DF935B0)
>
> VCL.Controls.TControl.Click

In my error handler, I get this a result similar to this with no parameter information:

> [00F9701D]{Test.exe} TestForm.DoSomething$qqrx20System.UnicodeString (Line 138, "TestForm.pas")
>
> [005E358B]{TestMonitor.exe} Vcl.Controls.TControl.Click$qqrv (Line 7340, "Vcl.Controls.pas")

I have initialised my error handling by calling during the units initialization section:

```
JclStackTrackingOptions:=JclStackTrackingOptions + [stStack, stRawMode];
JclStartExceptionTracking;
```

Then when the exception handler is invoked, I call the following to get the call stack strings:

```
JclLastExceptStackListToStrings(FErrors, True, False, False);
```

Is it possible to get the parameters the methods were called with using JCLDebug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible with jcldebug. I don't even know of any other tool that allows this unless it adds code to each method that explicitly writes this information to a log file (usually this process is called "instrumenting").